# Prototype 1.7 Object.extend doesn't work as it should when used in prototype class

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototypejs

I'm trying to use a simple OOP model in javascript but somehow I failed. I wrote a simple code to demonstrate my problem:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="scriptaculous/prototype.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var Person = Class.create({

  options : {},

  initialize: function(id, options) {
    this.id = id;
    Object.extend(this.options, options || {});
  },

  speak: function() {
    console.log(this.options);
  }
});
var person1 = new Person("abcd12",{
  name : "Jon Doe",
  age : 23
});
var person2 = new Person("cdef34",{
  name : "Jane Doe",
  age : 32
});
person1.speak();
//Object { name="Jane Doe", age=32}
person2.speak();
//Object { name="Jane Doe", age=32}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Obviously this is not at all what I want to achieve and since there is no proper documentation for Object.extend I don't know if this is normal or intended or not.

Thank you for your help

Comment: No proper documentation for Object.extend, ey? http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/extend/

Answer (score 0):

The "options" property is on the prototype object, which means that it's shared by all instances. That is, when you mention `this.options` in that expression, it's *not* putting a property directly on the new object (`this`), but instead it's *updating* the existing property found on the prototype.

Just take that line:

```
 options: {},
```

out.

I think I'd write the call to `Object.extend` as:

```
 this.options = Object.extend({}, options || {});
```

(*edit* — actually now that I think about it, it's all because `Object.extend` updates the passed-in first parameter directly. If you just changed the call to `Object.extend` it'd fix it I think, though there's really no reason to put it in the prototype anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, never thought about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's just because your code snippet is not complete, you're not actually doing any 'object extending', so you could just do this:

```
var Person = Class.create({

  initialize: function(id, options) {
    this.id = id;
    this.options = options;
  },
  ...
});
```

Here's an example of how to use Object.extend to merge the passed in `options` properties with default ones:

```
var Person = Class.create({

  initialize: function(id, options) {
    this.id = id;
    this.options = Object.extend({
      prop1: 'defaultValue1',
      bool1: true
    }, options);
  },
  ...
});
```

Using this code, if you did this:

```
var person = new Person('idString', {prop1: 'custom prop 1'});
```

Then `person.options` would yield:

```
{
  prop1: 'custom prop 1',
  bool1: true
}
```